# How to import multiple text files from a folder into one worksheet and fixed width?

Tags: vba

I have many text files in * .txt format in a folder, I want to import them all into a spreadsheet and "fixed width", then extract the desired information and paste it into another sheet, so What can I do?
I want to extract the necessary information from the imported worksheet via another spreadsheet like the one I attached below?
Best regards!
link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fdHgq9uQKtyNlNOvue7NkiZgq678RPQ9?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried anything so far ? If yes, mention that also in the question. This is not a free coding website.

Comment: Use PowerQuery.

Comment: Thank Mikku, Dean. I used to enter but did not divide the column width and all data on one line of the file * .txt will also be on a cell of the corresponding line on excel.
I also use PowerQuery, but I can only import 1 file at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option for you to consider.

```
Sub ReadFilesIntoActiveSheet()

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim Items() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range

' Get a FileSystem object
Set fso = New FileSystemObject

' get the directory you want
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\your_path_here\")

' set the starting point to write the data to
Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1)

' Loop thru all files in the folder
For Each file In folder.Files
    ' Write file-name
    cl.Value = file.Name

    ' Open the file
    Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

    ' Read the file one line at a time
    Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
        TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

        ' Parse the line into | delimited pieces
        Items = Split(TextLine, "|")

        ' Put data on one row in active sheet
        For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
            cl.Offset(0, 1 + i).Value = Items(i)
        Next

        ' Move to next row
        Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

    ' Clean up
    FileText.Close
Next file

Set FileText = Nothing
Set file = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Here is another option.

```
Sub ImportTXTFiles()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim xlsheet As Worksheet
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim txtfilesToOpen As Variant, txtfile As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    txtfilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
                 (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
                  MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")

    For Each txtfile In txtfilesToOpen
        LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        ' IMPORT DATA FROM TEXT FILE
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & txtfile, _
          Destination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1))
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"

            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

        For Each qt In ActiveSheet.QueryTables
            qt.Delete
        Next qt
    Next txtfile

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Successfully imported text files!", vbInformation, "SUCCESSFUL IMPORT"

    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```